# how to hide all categories with a hook WooCommerce shop page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i just need to hide/remove categories in my shop page under my picture with a simple hook

that what i want

[here my picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OQHP.png)

thank in advance

Comment: use inspect element find the class and then hide it with css

Comment: I said to myself the same thing but is not a bit dirty no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the hook `woocommerce_template_single_meta` in `content-single-product.php` :

In your functions.php file

```
remove_action('woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40);
```

You will find, in each Woocommerce templates files a commented lists of actions, corresponding to a template block, that you can move (or remove) when you change the priority (40 in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial that sounds like it would accomplish what you are looking to do.

https://www.ultimatewoo.com/how-to-remove-product-categories-from-woocommerce-shop-page/

However, it would probably be easier to hide that part of the page with CSS. If you put your cursor over the categories then right-click and select "Inspect" (chrome) or "Inspect Element" (firefox) you can find the class for that element.

Once you have the class selector you can do something like

```
.archive.woocommerce ul.products.cols-3 {
       display: none;
}
```

I tried to get more specific but I couldn't actually find a woocommerce demo site that had categories shown like yours.

If you are still having problems please provide a link to your shop page and I or someone else can help you pick the correct selector.